# .net button command adding programmatically

Tags: .net, asp.net, button, command

I have asp:button and foo function. I want to programmatically add foo function for command event to that button. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: @Shekhar actually i can not find anything useful

Comment: have you programmed in asp.net before?

Comment: @ub1k i am kind a newbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At an appropriate point in your page, assign the handler to the button's Command event:

```
btnButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(Foo);
```

And then the Foo method must have the following signature:

```
void Foo(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event handler (in your case, event handler will be foo() function) for `command` event.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command.aspx) you can get all the information about how to add event handler for `command` event.